# how to chose files to read from using nested try except?

Tags: python, exception, error-handling, try-catch, except

Depending on availability, I am trying to define a priority order of files to read from. I used nested Try Except and it works as expected. However, it's pretty cumbersome.

```
try :
    data_bachir = pd.read_table(model_data_path_1, nrows=73, infer_datetime_format = True, parse_dates = ["DATE"], sep='\s+',  engine='python') 
    Tmax_bachir = str(max(data_bachir.T2M.loc[0:23]))
except :
    try :
        data_bachir = pd.read_table(model_data_path_2, nrows=73, infer_datetime_format = True, parse_dates = ["DATE"], sep='\s+',  engine='python') 
        Tmax_bachir = str(max(data_bachir.T2M.loc[0:12])) 
    except :    
        try:
            data_bachir = pd.read_table(model_data_path_3, nrows=73, infer_datetime_format = True, parse_dates = ["DATE"], sep='\s+',  engine='python') 
            Tmax_bachir = str(max(data_bachir.T2M.loc[12:36])) 
        except : 
            data_bachir = pd.read_table(model_data_path_4, nrows=73, infer_datetime_format = True, parse_dates = ["DATE"], sep='\s+',  engine='python') 
            Tmax_bachir = str(max(data_bachir.T2M.loc[23:47]))
```

Is there a more elegant pythonic way to do this?

Comment: You could use `os.path.isfile()` to check which of the files exist before trying to access one of them. Then pass the correct filename/path into you try block. That way you can redurce nesting since you only need one try-except.

Comment: I see your point. So I'll end up with a 'If .. elif .. elif .. else' statement instead (to test the availability of the 4 files one after one). Is that the best It could be in you in your opinion ?

Comment: Yes, this is basically the python way of creating a switch-case-structure. After 3.10 there's a closer aproximation called `match`. If you use early returns (put the check-block in a function and use `return`in order to stop evaluating the if/elif/elses and continue with the next step, in your case reading files), you do quite a bit of optimization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another, compacter and scaleable approach, using list+loop:

```py
import os


def find_existing_sourcefile(file_list):
  for file in file_list:
    if os.path.isfile(file):
      return file
  return None  # if loop ends without returning something, this is returned.

def do_pandas_stuff():
  file_list = ['model_data_path_1', 'model_data_path_2', 'model_data_path_3', 'model_data_path_4']
  file = find_existing_sourcefile(file_list)
  try:
    data_bachir = pd.read_table(file, nrows=73, infer_datetime_format = True, parse_dates = ["DATE"], sep='\s+',  engine='python') 
    Tmax_bachir = str(max(data_bachir.T2M.loc[0:23]))
  except:   # would be better to use named exceptions here.
    print("No valid source file found")
    
do_pandas_stuff()
```

Comment: This is way more elegant! Thanks man